# Formatting several strings into one whilst maintaining layout

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, string-formatting

I have a listbox which i am populating with data; a string of variable length and 3 ints formatted to fixed lengths.

I can't work out how to get the string text to take up only x characters

i.e.

30 characters worth of space, if string is 5 characters long add 25 characters worth of padding. If string is 10 characters long add 20 characters of padding.

My latest attempt looked like:

```
int padding = 30 - item.ProductName.Length;
string prodName = String.Format("{0, " + padding + "}",item.ProductName);
string quant = String.Format("{0,15}", item.GetQuantity);
string price = String.Format("{0,30:C2}", item.LatestPrice);
string total = String.Format("{0,30:C2}", item.TotalOrder);
string temp = prodName + quant + price + total;
return temp;
```

But that's still not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhzZP.png

Comment: Use a DataGridView control.

Comment: Unfortunately the spec calls for a listbox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
//int padding = 30 - item.ProductName.Length;
string prodName = String.Format("{0, -30}", item.ProductName);
string quant = String.Format("{0,15}", item.GetQuantity);
string price = String.Format("{0,30:C2}", item.LatestPrice);
string total = String.Format("{0,30:C2}", item.TotalOrder);
string temp = prodName + quant + price + total;
return temp;
```

And if you want Product Names absolutely limited to 30 characters then you'll need to truncate Product Names > 30 characters.

```
string prodName = String.Format("{0, -30}", item.ProductName.Length > 30 ? item.ProductName.Substring(0,30): item.ProductName);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also had to switch the font of my listbox to Lucida Console to get it to work.